# How to executed multiple paragraph searches (with updates) on new Word document in Office.js?

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to update a set of paragraphs in a new Word document via Office.js.  The code below is an asynchronous chain which loops in sequence as expected.  The first call to search a paragraph returns the `rangeCollection` correctly, but all subsequent calls return a null `seachResults.items` object.

Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury of being able to do a full document search.  I already have a known list of paragraph index(es) that I need to locate along with known text within those paragraphs to highlight

Any ideas?

```js
var processDocAsync = function (context, paragraphs, onComplete) {

    // A recursive helper function to work on the n'th paragraph
    function getAndProcessParagraph(index) {

        // stop processing
        if (index == paragraphs.items.length) {
            onComplete();
        } else {
            // Main recursive case

            // search the indexth paragraph
            var options = Word.SearchOptions.newObject(context);
            options.matchCase = false

            var searchResults = paragraphs.items[index].search('the', options);
            context.load(searchResults, 'text, font');

            context.sync().then(function () {

                // Highlight all the "THE" words in this paragraph
                try {

                    // Queue a command to change the font for each found item. 
                    if (searchResults.items) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < searchResults.items.length; j++) {
                            searchResults.items[j].font.color = '#FF0000'
                            searchResults.items[j].font.highlightColor = '#FFFF00';
                            searchResults.items[j].font.bold = true;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (myError) {
                    console.log(myError.message);
                }

                // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued-up commands, 
                // then move on to the next paragraph
                return context.sync().then(getAndProcessParagraph(index + 1));
            });
        }
    }

    // Begin the recursive process with the first slice.
    getAndProcessParagraph(0);
}

var openProcessedDoc = function (base64str, documentId) {

    Word.run(function (context) {

        var myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument(base64str);
        context.load(myNewDoc);

        var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
        paragraphs.load(paragraphs, 'text, font');

        return context.sync().then(function () {
            processDocAsync(context, paragraphs, processCompleted)
        });
    });
};

var processCompleted = function () {
    console.log('Process completed');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

excellent question. this is a typical case of how to traverse a collection within a collection with promises and async patterns.

[Please setup script lab](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380862&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false) (a cool  add-in you can use to try code snippets). Jump to 7:46 [on this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V85_97G7VA4) to see how to load the yaml.

[load this yaml](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/d02ffdd010f36b0acdf570682e15d99a) in script lab  and see an example of how you can do this. the sample is not exactly what you need (it basically traverses a collection of words within a paragraph instead) but hopefully  you can mimic this pattern  for your specific scenario.

happy coding!